# Rails Flash message is not shown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a line in a controller that will redirect to the home screen with a custom flash message, like so:

```
redirect_to :controller => :home, :action => :index, :alert => "You are not yet assigned to an experiment." and return
```

The user is then redirected to the following page: `http://localhost:3000/home?alert=You+are+not+yet+assigned+to+an+experiment`

However, the flash message is not shown, although all other flash messages work in my application. The *views/layouts/application.html.erb* file contains the following:

```
<div class="flash">
    <%- if !notice.nil? -%>
    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <%- end -%> 
    <%- if !alert.nil? -%>
    <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
    <%- end -%>     
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flash is using session to store messages

```
flash[:alert] = "You are not yet assigned to an experiment."
redirect_to :controller => :home, :action => :index and return
<%= flash[:alert] %>
```

If you want to pass it through params you should use params[:param_name]

```
redirect_to :controller => :home, :action => :index, :alert => "You are not yet assigned to an experiment." and return
<%= params[:alert] %>
```

Flash is more preferable, it works implicitly across pages and is cleared after it's shown

Comment: Thanks, that was precisely what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

In your view, you access a notice flash message by using

```
<%= flash[:notice] %>
```

not

```
<%= notice %>
```

The same applies to alert.

Also, there's an error in your code.

```
redirect_to :controller => :home, :action => :index, :alert => "You are not yet assigned to an experiment."
```

must be

```
redirect_to({ :controller => :home, :action => :index }, :alert => "You are not yet assigned to an experiment.")
```

Comment: If I change the `<%= alert %>` to `<%= flash[:alert] %>` (and the `if` clause), still no message is shown.